# Validation Rules created using Standard Out of Box to get dynamically applicable in Visual Force pages

Tags: visualforce

We are  Changing our Standard SFDC pages to Visual force pages  . Where we are modifying our Save and edit functionality. As we are going to modify all our standard pages we are facing a road block with validation rules.

We are looking for one time thing where we can  add validations as in standard out of the box functionality (Errors popping up at top of page and at field level), to reflect directly in visual force build pages instead of adding apex errors or deploy it every time we add a new validation.

We tried using

```
<apex:pageMessages
```

and

```
<apex:messages
```

but didnt work out. Please suggest how can we accomplish this. Any sample codes is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Validation rules should work when used with Visualforce. You need to use the correct tag `apex:pageMessages` or `apex:messages` to have the message appear on the page is all. Validation rules throw the same exception as Apex validation: `DMLException`. Maybe you can edit your question above and provide more details as to what you've tried as opposed to the conclusion that Validation rules won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your save button rerenders your `pageMessages` element on save, and also make sure your save method returns a null `PageReference`.

```
public PageReference save()
{
    try
    {
        //save record
    }
    catch (DmlException dmx)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(dmx);
        return null;
    }
    return redirect;
}
```

VF:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" reRender="msgs" />
<apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />
```